# Is there is a transformation function that transform values to -1 to 1 in R

Tags: r

I am looking for a function similar to the logistic function, but instead of bounding the values between 0 to 1. I want it to transform the values to the range of -1 to 1.

I have some data that ranges from -1 to 1. I then fit a model and based on estimated coefficients and variance I simulate some data from a normal distribution. But some values are outside the range of -1 to 1. I was wondering if there is a function to convert all values a range of -1 to 1.

Thank you

Comment: Just stretch the logistic out. Do a logistic transform (0 to 1),  multiply by 2  (0 to 2), then subtract 1 (-1 to 1).

Comment: But also, maybe just sample from a bounded distribution? Instead of sampling from a normal, you could sample from a Beta(2, 2) (which is bounded between 0 and 1) and transform it to -1,1 as described above.

Answer (score 1):

`2*atan(x)/pi` or `2*F(x)-1` for any suitable cumulative distribution function `F` will do.

```
curve(2 * atan(x) / pi, -5, 5, col = 1)
curve(2*pnorm(x)-1, -5, 5, col = 2, add = TRUE)
curve(2*pt(x, 5)-1, -5, 5, col = 3, add = TRUE)
curve(2*plogis(x)-1, -5, 5, col = 4, add = TRUE)
legend("topleft", c("2*atan/pi", "2*pnorm-1", "2*pt-1", "2*plogis-1"), lty = 1, col = 1:4)
```

[image: screenshot]